# Making cell contents appear flush with the edge of the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to get the cell text exactly flush with the left side of the table view.  I tried setting tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0), which works fine for scroll views, but with the tableView, the content still appears just a little to the right.

Does anyone know the exact number I need to make the content be flush with the side of the table view, or perhaps a different way to do this?

This is what I mean (how the blue letters are off to the right):

[image]

(^This is with the default contentInset)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the table view's contentInset isn't the right approach. The cells already go to the edge of the table. You can verify this by setting the cell's background color. By default, the cell's `textLabel` is setup to be in a bit from the edge. You should try adjusting the frame of the cell's `textLabel`. The best place for this is most likely to be the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Another option is a custom table view cell that puts the text where you want it within the cell and not rely on changing the default setup.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best approach is to create an instance UILabel variable then initialise the UILabel in your cellForRow:AtIndexPath: method.

You can define the frame to whatever you like. Give it a tag number.

Once you're ready, add the UILabel as a subview to your cell.contentView.

```
// .h file
@interface MyClass
{
    UILabel *lblCellText;
}

// .m file
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeReusableCellWithID:cellID];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle.....];

        // ------------------------------------
        // initialise your UILabel here
        // ------------------------------------
        lblCellText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.rowHeight)];
        lblCellText.tag = 1;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCellText];

        [lblCellText release];
    }

    // find your UILabel from the pool of dequed UITableViewCells
    lblCellText = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    lblCellText.text = "New playlist";


    return cell;
}
```